# Cannot capture exception with Sentry

Tags: java, error-handling, sentry

I'm initializing my Sentry intance like this:

```java
Sentry.init(options -> {
            options.setDsn("https://****@****.ingest.sentry.io/****");
            options.setTracesSampleRate(1.0);
            options.setDebug(true);
        });
```

I'm them capturing an exception like this:

```java
Sentry.captureException(new Error("Generic error"));
```

When I capture something like that, this is my result I get:

```json
[10.07 13:01:43.027] INFO: [Lobby-1] [13:01:42 INFO]: DEBUG: Capturing event: 187ae6cca0604c72b84a0429d3bc95c8
[10.07 13:01:43.027] INFO: [Lobby-1] [13:01:42 INFO]: INFO: Session is null on scope.withSession
[10.07 13:01:43.027] INFO: [Lobby-1] [13:01:42 INFO]: ERROR: Request failed, API returned 400
[10.07 13:01:43.027] INFO: [Lobby-1] [13:01:42 INFO]: ERROR: {"detail":"empty envelope"}
```

I've also tried by just throwing the error and let Sentry handle the unhandled error but that doesn't log anything except the thrown error.

I also some posts talking about a specific gson version. Even though I don't use it in my project I added it to my gradle dependencies but that still results in the same issue. These are the currently installed GSON versions:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This error can happen if you have an older version of `Gson` than Sentry requires. You might not depend on `Gson` directly but it might be a transient dependency.

Sentry depends on [Gson version 2.8.5](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/3739f6775ea13bb3bfe01d66df2765bc35636e7e/buildSrc/src/main/java/Config.kt#L50) and when an older version is resolved this issue can happen. Make sure to add this version or higher to your gradle project.

Note that [Sentry is working on dropping the dependency to `Gson`](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/1537) which will result in a dependency-free package.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my currently installed Gson versions, these seem perfectly fine right?

Comment: Yeah that looks good. To confirm: That's on sentry.io right? Not Self Hosted Sentry? Could you please create a small reproducible project and put on a GitHub repository (or just share as a zip) so we can take a look?